# How can I manipulate database in stack n-up order?

Tags: database-design

I need to print a mail merge 3-up.  The database ( Micorsoft Access ) is in order of ID 1 to 1845.  Instead of printing sheet#1 (ID 1, 2, 3)  I'd like to print sheet#1 (ID 1, 616, 1231) and so on.  The purpose is to stack each pile after I cut it and then it's in order.  I don't want to end up with 3 piles in order.
How can I set up my database in ID order to print every 615th record starting from ID #1?

Database should look like:

```
**ID**      **Address**
1       123 Sample Street
616     987 Hello Road
1231    456 Print Avenue
2       999 Access Parkway
617     111 Boogie Court
1232    555 Database Sreet
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the modulo function in Access is, but if I were to write an SQL query I'd use this to order the records:

```
...order by case mod(id,615) when 0 then 615 else mod(id, 615) end, id
```